# so, my Cassandra consultant left me and now I'm thinking about reverting to mysql

Tags: mysql, cassandra

I run a middle size community and some time ago I started to develop social capabilities such as follow, status update, wall etc.

For some reason i thought that Cassandra was the right tool for the job so I looked online for a Cassandra developer and I found a very talented one.

Unluckily in the midst of the development the dev left (too much jobs) and so I'm here with a very nice class, a very nice demo, but a lot of fears that I won't be able to handle basic things such as compaction, scaling etc.

My biggest fear is to go online with all this coolness and then having a site inaccessible for hours or days.

The mysql consultant (very talented too) keeps saying me that I should stick with Mysql which I know rather well and in case something's wrong we can manage.

In that case I should take the class made for cassandra and abstract it for Mysql.

My question is this:
Should I find another dev/consultant and stick with Cassandra because for social things it is definitely the best tool for the job, or should I listen to the Mysql consultant and revert to Mysql?

About 15k login each day
Average 20 actions per user
Avg 6 followers x user

(These are current statistics, but of course I'd like to increase them as much as possible.)

Comment: this question is already solliciting debat, discussion, opinions, and therefore not a good fit for SO. You could try your luck at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers you mention are nowhere near the boundaries of MySQL - you could grow by a factor of 100 and still be quite comfortable on MySQL (depending, as always, on the datamodel, hardware, caching etc.).

I'd stick with MySQL for now, and concentrate on adding new features to grow the community. It's easier to find developers with MySQL experience, it's easier to get community support, there are existing frameworks and toolsets to help you with scalability.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a developer yourself, id say you should stick with your cassandra setup for a while and learn it. Cassandra is very different from what you previously know, and it will only make you a better programmer if you learn it.

You should be able to figure how stuff works just by looking at the stuff your previous consultant has made, and by toying around (which is proven to be the best way to learn stuff).

When you are an intermediate user of cassandra, then make the decision. Are you missing things from mysql? (in previous versions of cassandra, there were no auto_increment feature) And if so, write a script that plugs all your stuff from cassandra into your mysql database.

This is a great opportunity for a great learning experience.

Comment: yes, it sounds good from the learning stuff perspective. but I don't have undefined time for shipping the code and most importantly I don't want to go online just to see my servers melt and having no idea (or little) on what to do.